# STM32F4 USART not correctly configured

Tags: stm32, uart, stm32f4, nucleo

I'm trying to manually* configure a USART on a Nucleo F401RE to transmit over the USB virtual COM port, which means using USART2 on PA2 (TX) and PA3 (RX). Not only am I not receiving any characters, but the TX pin is never high, which I believe it should be when idle.

Here's what I've done:

PLL is running at 84MHz (confirmed using MCO), and the APB1 prescaler is set to /2:

```
RCC_CFGR = 
    (2 << RCC_CFGR_SW_BIT) // Use PLL as clock source
    | (0b100 << RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_BIT) // Prescale APB1 clock /2
;
```

GPIOA peripheral clock is enabled:

```
// Enable GPIOA peripheral clock
RCC_AHB1ENR = RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
```

Then the USART configuration:

```
GPIOA_MODER |= 0b1010 << 4; // PA2, PA3 to AF
GPIOA_OSPEEDR |= 0b1111 << 4; // PA2, PA3 to high speed
GPIOA_AFRL |= (7 << 8) | (7 << 12); // Set PA2, PA3 to AF7 (USART2)
RCC_APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_USART2EN; // Enable peripheral clock for USART2

// Baud rate 115k2 with SYSCLK 84MHz (BRR = 45.5625)
USART2_BRR = (45 << 4) | 9;

USART2_CR1 = USART_CR1_UE | USART_CR1_TE;
```

I believe at this point, TX should be high, but it isn't. I send with:

```
while ((USART2_SR & USART_SR_TXE) == 0);
USART2_DR = c;
```

Turning on the LED within the `while` shows that the transmit buffer is initially filled. Turning it on after the `while` shows that it successfully empties. Using `TC` instead of `TXE` shows it is considered successfully transmitted.

What have I missed?

All the code is here: https://github.com/danellis/zeptos/tree/usart-fail

---

* *Please don't try to persuade me to use CMSIS or mbed; it's a learning exercise.*

Comment: no one will read the magic numbers.

Comment: So assume they're correct.

Comment: BTW you are setting the registers in a potentially dangerous way. You should clear the existing bit values before applying the OR operation. For example, add GPIOA_MODER &= ~(0xF << 4); for that register. This will save your colleagues (and future self) from many hours of debugging.

Comment: @Jon Eventually, yes. I have a YAML file of register descriptions to generate the appropriate macros for any fields wider than one bit. For now, they take the reset values into consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the code was fine, and it was all hardware issues. Firstly, the USART2 TX/RX pins on that board's connector are by design not connected to anything. The MCU pins are only connected to the ST-Link. (There are solder bridges to change this configuration.) So that's why I didn't get anything on the scope.

As for why I didn't get any data on the USB port, I think the ST-Link was not compatible with USB 3.0. When I upgraded its firmware, suddenly I saw my data.